# Changing text after an input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I change the "2 Year Subscription" to "2 year:" without losing the input field

```
<div class="radioOption subscription1Col3">
<input class="buyNow" type="radio" name="product2" value="6_0" checked="">2 Year Subscription</div>
```

Comment: I do not have the slightest idea what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "losing" the input field?

Comment: He means if he did a `$('.subscription1Col3').html('some text')` it'll remove the input too, as it's a child of the container.

Comment: this can be done, but in a rather complicated way. I would recommend to put the text in a paragraph or label element (<p id="p1">2 Year Subscription</p>) and to simply change its value when required

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively simple, and I'd suggest the following (though currently untested):

```
var input = $('.radioOption.subscription1Col3 input'),
    text = input[0].nextSibling.nodeValue,
    newText = text.replace(/ subscription/i,': ');
input[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = newText;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x5SwP/).

Or possibly this version might be preferred, since it leaves the adjusted text wrapped in a `label` element, which aids UI and makes it easier to target that text content in future:

```
var input = $('#inputID'),
    label = $('<label />',{'for' : 'inputID'})
    .text(input[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/ Subscription/i,': '));
input.parent().empty().append(input, label);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x5SwP/1/).

This does, though, require the `input` to have an `id` attribute so that the `label` is semantically attached to that `input`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't support accessing text nodes, only elements, so you would need to use the DOM methods in Javascript to access the text node:

```
var nodes = $('.radioOption')[0].childNodes;
nodes[nodes.length-1].nodeValue= '2 Year';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/PDqQW/

If you put an element around the text:

```
<div class="radioOption subscription1Col3">
  <input class="buyNow" type="radio" name="product2" value="6_0" checked="">
  <span>2 Year Subscription</span>
</div>
```

Then you can use just jQuery to access it:

```
$('.radioOption span').text('2 Year');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tRdYa/

Answer (score 1):

Another way will be to change the `textContent`

```
$('.buyNow')[0].nextSibling.textContent = "New Content"
```